# How can I send a notification by using the email inserted by another user who requested the notification using Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm a beginner on Cloud Functions for Firebase and I'm developing a web app using it to send notifications to specific users. However, the problem is that I want to let the user decid for who he wants to send the message, and the way I've found out to do this was allowing the user to insert through a form in my site the receiver's email, so that I could save it in my database and then activate a function that would send a previously created notification to the registered user who had the same email inserted by the sender user.

So, I know that I have to trigger the function whenever a user sends the form with the receiver's email, since it's when my database is changed. However, I don't know how to compare the email inserted with the email of all others users and then catch only the right user's token to send the notification. Does anyone know how to do this?

These are my code, which I took some parts of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712989/android-firebase-cloud-function-notification) as a base, and the JSON from part of my database:

**Function**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendPush = 
functions.database.ref('/Messages/Receivers/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {

const snapshot = event.data;

const email = snapshot.val().email;
const getAllUsersPromise = admin.database().ref('Users/').once('value');

const payload = {

    notification: {
        title: 'You have a notification',
        body: 'You received a new message'
    }

};

return getAllUsersPromise.then(result => {
    const userUidSnapShot = result;

    const users = Object.keys(userUidSnapShot.val());

    var AllUsersFCMPromises = []; 
    for (var i = 0;i<userUidSnapShot.numChildren(); i++) {
        const user=users[i];
        console.log('getting promise of user uid=',user);
        AllUsersFCMPromises[i]= admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user}/email`).equalTo(email).once('value').then(token => {
            var token = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user}/token`).once('value');
            return token; 
        });
    }

    return Promise.all(AllUsersFCMPromises).then(results => {

        var tokens = []; 
        for(var i in results){
            var usersTokenSnapShot=results[i];
            console.log('For user = ',i);
            if(usersTokenSnapShot.exists()){
                if (usersTokenSnapShot.hasChildren()) { 
                    const t=  Object.keys(usersTokenSnapShot.val()); 
                    tokens = tokens.concat(t); 
                    console.log('token[s] of user = ',t);
                }
                else{

                }
            }
        }
        console.log('final tokens = ',tokens," notification= ",payload);
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {

            const tokensToRemove = [];
            response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
                const error = result.error;
                if (error) {
                    console.error('Failure sending notification to uid=', tokens[index], error);

                    if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' || error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                        tokensToRemove.push(usersTokenSnapShot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
                    }
                }
                else{
                    console.log("notification sent",result);
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
});
});
```

**JSON Structure**

```
    {  
  "Messages" : {
    "Receivers" : {
      "-Ko-Gc8Ch58uYKGIT_Ze" : {
        "email" : "phgrespan@gmail.com"
      },
    }
  },

  "Users" : {
    "1rwdq0O9Iqdo1JUNauwmlC9HXfY2" : {
      "apartamento" : "12",
      "bloco" : "L",
      "celular" : "148162491784",
      "email" : "jose@gmail.com",
      "nome" : "josé",
      "sobrenome" : "josé",
      "telefone" : "418947912497",
      "token" : "een1HZ0ZzP0:APA91bHaY06dT68W3jtlC3xykcnnC7nS3zaNiKBYOayBq-wuZsbv1DMFL8zE6oghieYkvvSn39bDCkXLtc3pfC82AGd8-uvmkuXCkPoTuzxMk14wVQNOB01AQ6L7bmsQBisycm2-znz7"
    }, 
    "CZv1oxUkfsVpbXNBMQsUZNzSvbt1" : {
      "apartamento" : "8",
      "bloco" : "P",
      "celular" : "123456789",
      "email" : "phgrespan@gmail.com",
      "nome" : "Pedro",
      "sobrenome" : "Henrique",
      "telefone" : "99876543234",
      "token" : "dvE4gBh1fwU:APA91bF9zLC1cOxT4jLsfPRdsxE8q0Z9P4uKuZlp8M5fIoxWd2MOS30u4TLuOQ4G2Sg0mlDqFMuzvjX3_ZSSi9XATyGtTtNse4AxwLYuD-Piw9oFn6Ma68nGfPSTnIEpvDYRwVnRI2e4"
    },
  }
}
```

I hope I have been able to make myself understood and thanks since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're querying all users when you only need to query the user or users who have the selected email. Instead of using `getAllUsersPromise`, use `.orderByChild()` and query the children whose email is equal to the selected email.

```
let selectedUsers = admin.database.ref('Users/').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once(snap => {
    // Get the token
})
```

This will give you the snapshot of just the user or users who have that email. You can then iterate through the snapshots and get the token(s).

Comment: Well, first thank you for answering, but I tried to do what you said and I'm still having trouble to catch the token. To do that I'm trying this: `var token = snap.val().token;`, but when I tried to see its value in the console, it showed `undefined`. So, could you show me the right way to do that?