# Triggers on Firebase for Push Notifications

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Are there any triggers on Firebase database like in MySQL which I can use to automate push notification? I need to avoid manual push notification from Firebase console. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Look into [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).  It offers [database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) which can respond to changes to your database at the location you specify.

There is [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) that demonstrates how to [send a notification in response to a changes to a database](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications).

Answer (score 1):

First method

You can push notification from the android side by retrieving the token from the firebase database for that you have to store the token of each device to the Firebase database.

Second method

You can use Firebase function for the automatic push notification. Use this link [Android Firebase cloud function notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712989/android-firebase-cloud-function-notification)